# Does Microsoft 'Identity Platform' (easily) integrate with the '(ASP.NET) Identity Framework' - MVC5 & .NET 4.7.2?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, microsoft-identity-platform

We have a .NET 4.7.2 MVC5 app that uses the EF additions to the usage of the Microsoft Identity Framework, and was wondering if it's easy to combine - in some way or another, the MSAL.NET/Identity Platform?

E.g. ideally, keep the Identity Framework for local logins and supplement it with the Identity Platform OAuth v2 integration for Azure AD & Azure AD B2C (external identity/user) logins?

- Is this supported?
- Are there major issues?
- Is it easy to plug in?
- What's the best route?

I can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere.

UPDATE:  Ignoring demo's that either require .NET Core 3.1 or a specific version (# 27) of Android (- when the 'Android SDK Manager' tool does not work due to it trying to modify an enumeration that it's in the process of enumerating :( ) I managed to apply a couple of changes to the ASP.NET 'Quickstart' app to get that working, but when I try to aim smaller by replacing bits of the (ASP.NET) identity framework code within our existing app with the code from the quickstart sample's identity platform code, I just seem to get stuck in a instant sign-in circle.

Comment: "*what's the best route*" You're asking for a tutorial/best practice here, what did you do so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the best answer but for the benefit of others, this is what I'd learnt, and personally think.

Currently, there does not seem to be an explicit/assisted transition path.

However, I did find a way to manually transition from one to the other (- '(ASP.NET) Identity Framework' to 'Identity Platform'/Azure AD B2C/MSAL), which also left me with the following conclusion:

> Rather than have inherent support for different IdP/AS (Identity Provider / Authentication Server) vendors' OID-C/OIDC (OpenID Connect) and/or OAuth pipelines - potentially all their pipelines possibly tripping up all over another/each other (as part of a more instrinsic wiring-in), and also having to re-test the whole of the application for all vendors upon the addition of a new IdP/AS vendor, I figured the best way is to translate the vendor's id-token to our own access-token or rather more directly our existing ClaimsPrincipal.

So in terms of some of the mechanics of the solution; having added the following NuGet package (with it's underlying dependencies):

```
    <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="6.7.1" targetFramework="net472" />
```

(... although version '6.8.0' is now available.)

I was then able to use code like the following, to verify the 'id_token', which in turn returns a 'ClaimsPrincipal'; I can then use the value of the 'e-mail' claim to check for an existing user within our system - and if not create a new user (with a random & secure password and the first & last names and hopefully their mobile # too):

```
    var viewModel =
        new
        {
            IdToken =
                idToken
        };

    // Application (client) ID
    var msIdPfClientId =
        @"...";

    // Application (client) URI
    var msIdPfClientUri =
        @"...";

    // Directory (tenant) ID
    var msIdPfTenantId =
        @"...";

    // Valid Issuer
    var msIdPfValidIssuer =
        @"...";

    var identityModelConfigManager =
        new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
            $"{msIdPfValidIssuer}/.well-known/openid-configuration",
            new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());

    var oidcConfig =
        await identityModelConfigManager.GetConfigurationAsync();

    ISecurityTokenValidator securityTokenValidator =
        new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    // Initialize the token validation parameters
    var tokenValidationParameters =
        new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // App Id URI and AppId of this service application are both valid audiences.
            ValidAudiences =
                new[]
                {
                    msIdPfClientId,
                    msIdPfClientUri
                },
            ValidIssuer =
                msIdPfValidIssuer,
            //// Support Azure AD V1 and V2 endpoints
            //ValidIssuers =
            //    validIssuers,
            // ValidateIssuer = true,
            IssuerSigningKeys =
                oidcConfig.SigningKeys
        };

    var claimsPrincipal =
        securityTokenValidator.ValidateToken(
            viewModel.IdToken,
            tokenValidationParameters,
            out var validatedSecurityToken);
```

And then at the appropriate juncture soon after, I can then proceed to sign the user in with/in the tradition (ASP.NET) Identity Framework way:

```
    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(
                            user,
                            isPersistent: false,
                            rememberBrowser: false);
```

Although, I also found it useful to also create a cookie to indicate that the user had logged-in via the Identity Platform (- useful during the log-out process).

There's one other conclusion that I've come to recently - at least I feel it's a better choice for me if not also potentially others; and that's to shy away from the Microsoft 'Identity Platform' in it's MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library) specific/extended guise, and just treat/use it as a vanilla 'Connect'/OIDC/OID-C integration (with the underlying Azure AD - with no custom workflow branching into/requirement for BC/aka 'Azure AD BC').